# Correct typography for using Leibniz Notation

Tags: calculus, derivatives, notation

What is the correct way of writing derivatives in notation form? Should the 'd' be upright or italic, that is $\mathrm d$ or $d\,$? As an example, should we write:
$$ \frac {\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\qquad\text{or}\qquad \frac {dy}{dx} \, \text ?$$

I feel the first method (upright 'd') is correct, since italic letters are generally used for variables, but most people (and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz's_notation)) use the italic 'd'. Which is actually more correct?

Also, *how do we use this notation on notebooks (writing by hand)*, while avoiding potential confusion in a variable $d$ and the differential symbol? Since mostly we write variables upright on notebooks, so $\displaystyle \mathrm{\frac{dd}{dt}}$ in a notebook would be potentially confusing. (Of course, we could avoid a variable 'd', but still, what would be another way out of this?)

Comment: I can't imagine a situation where it would make a difference. It should be clear from context regardless of if the letters are italicized or not.

Comment: The `esdiff` package does it by default (including for partial derivatives) and has a simple syntax, useful for higher order derivatives. Often people use italic letters by pure laziness.

Comment: The vast majority of mathematics journals and books use italic $d$, I think. But there exists an international standard for notation in technical and engineering fields that specifies the upright $\mathrm{d}$ for this purpose, and similarly for $\mathrm{i}=\sqrt{-1}$ and $\mathrm{e}=2.71828…$ (sorry, I don't have the reference on hand).

Comment: Not only for technical and engineering fields. It's been used in French mathematics for many years.

Comment: Sooner or later you'll have to pay for using the upright ${\rm d}$, because it's ISO-certified.

Comment: I have read widely in engineering and can't remember ever seeing upright d's, i's (often written $j$), and e's.  While some French works use non-italicized capitals I don't think they used non-italic d's. An example which you can download from Google Books is https://books.google.com/books?id=DEZMAAAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=goursat+cours+d%27analyse&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjdlZfooeHLAhVCPiYKHergB04Q6AEINzAD#v=onepage&q=goursat%20cours%20d%27analyse&f=false

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Why isn't $\iota$ (iota) used for $\sqrt{-1}$ (Wikipedia says $i$ for that one)? I am just curious to know. Also, is the international standard you are referring to, the ISO?

Comment: How can one possibly answer a question like the $\iota$ one? There are a lot of letters that *could* be used, but aren't. Yes, it's an ISO standard, though when I last saw it years and years ago, it was as an NS (Norwegian Standard, which follows the ISO standards closely).

Answer (score 1):

It is most common to use italic $d$, probably at least in part because that's the default LaTeX does. I have adopted a habit of handwriting with cursive to help distinguish symbols.

I write mostly in print, but I write $dx$ cursive and conjoined, which emphasizes that the two letters form one mathematical symbol. I write the differential operator as a cursive $d$ not conjoined with the following text.

Comment: TeX was much later (early 1980s) than the prevalence of italics in mathematics.

Comment: I liked the cursive idea for notebooks! Just one more thing, what about on computers (like on websites such as Math.SE)? Do you know about the standard there?

Comment: @ForgotALot yes, I only mean that it's current prevalence is in part because its been built into the system

Comment: @FreezingFire on websites such as MSE we are writing in LaTeX. Other places with built in equation editors, I just use the default, because I don't use built in equation editors enough it to be a big deal